# Using hidden input value in an AJAX action after setting it

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, hidden-field

I have a command button that sends some browser info in a backing bean using Javascript (by setting hidden input value) on click event and then executes AJAX action using that data. Hidden input gets that data correctly (checked with jQuery in a browser's console), but when action is executed, that data is not available. If I click on a command button the second time, data IS available. I believe that I must update hidden input value on a server-side before AJAX action is executed, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve that.

My code:

```
// Javascript function
getClientSideData: function() {
    var data = // some string containing browser info
    $('[id$=hidClientSideData]').val(data);
}

// HTML
<p:commandButton id="btnOK" value="OK" action="#{backingBean.doBtnOK}" onclick="getClientSideData();" process="@(.pghiddenfields)"/>

<h:panelGroup id="pgHiddenFields" styleClass="pghiddenfields" >
    <h:inputHidden id="hidClientSideData" 
        value="#{backingBean.clientSideData}" immediate="true" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

So, I would like to send some string from Javascript code (client-side) to backing bean and use it in ajax action on the same button. How can I change my code to get that data in an action?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow your explanation, as in your code the commandButton is not processed and the action therefore not executed (?)

If I change

```
getClientSideData: function() {
```

to

```
function getClientSideData() {
```

and put the script in h:head, and put

```
process="@(.pghiddenfields), @this"
```

on the button it works as you expect. Also without `immediate="true"`. I'm using a `ViewScoped` bean, and have it all in a single form.

If it still does'nt work for you, I guess there is some other problem you are not showing.